# How do I customize the alert template to select only the Content columns when sending an alert from a microfeed

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed, custom-alert-templates, alert

I want to send a alerts when ever anyone coments on the newsfeed. [image: News Feed]!

Although currently to set an alert on a newsfeed you have to set the alert on a microfeed.

[image: Micro feed]!

Instead of all the information that is sent in the email, I just want the content to be sent. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Online so you can **not** change anything Server-Side, with: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0/

Your only option then is to create a Workflow and send an email.