# Generating an email alert workflow not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow

[image: Workflow]

I built this workflow attached to my Microfeed and it doesn't seem to be working.

[image: Microfeed]

Does anyone know why this isnt working?

What I have

[image]

My Micro Feed
[image]

Comment: Is MicroFeed your custom list?

Comment: No this is the MicroFeed from SharePoint http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183188/how-do-i-customize-the-alert-template-to-select-only-the-content-columns-when-se/183195#183195

Comment: You can select the same from the list when you try creating the list workflow.
Than after you just need to make workflow start automatically on item added

Comment: Please check my answer.. Might be the same way but it will help you

Comment: Is that works for you?

Comment: I can't find how to create a loop in a site workflow :((((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First You have to create a Site workflow for this.Not a list workflow for site feed.

In the site workflow we have to create a loop.

[image]

Site Workflow

In the workflow first we have to create an infinite loop and wait for a item adding event for Microfeed list.

[image]

Then in the email action we can add lookups for the attributes in the item.

[image]

In the add look up window we can use following settings to get the values in the item.

[image]

Save and publish the workflow. Now it will send an email to the users mentioned in the workflow once a new post is added to the site feed/news feed/micro feed.

**UPDATED**

To add an alert in the **MicroFeed** list, please follow the steps below:

1. In your team site, click **Settings** > **Site contents** > **MicroFeed**.
2. Click **LIST** > **Alert Me** > **Set alert** on this list.
3. Type in the user names in the **Send Alert To** box and click **OK**.

Comment: For lookup string do I just type in "Variable: related item"

Comment: Mentioned here how to do lookup.

Comment: I have everything except the value column in the Look Up String under find the List Item

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Comment: I posted a picture of what I have done so far. It isnt send the email though. =(

Comment: I already mentioned that use Site workflow for this Not a list workflow. Your image shown that you had used list workflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40853/discussion-between-hardik-and-michael-downey).