# Site Workflow creation - Microfeed list on SP2013 (update)

Tags: list

About the post from here:
[Generating an email alert workflow not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183196/generating-an-email-alert-workflow-not-working/229205#229205)

I've tried to create a Site Workflow but I cannot set the value 1 equals 1 in the section "The contents of this loop will run repeatedly while 1 equals 1".

Any suggestion?

## Thanks a lot

Update: I've found the way to set the values:
[image]