# Site Workflow for Microfeed

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, site, loop

Re this post:
[Generating an email alert workflow not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183196/generating-an-email-alert-workflow-not-working/229205#229205)

I created a Site Workflow, but I'm not sure how to create the Loop, or the condition "The contents of this loop will run repeatedly while 1 equals 1."

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use **Loop** in a workflow, you need to make sure your workflow is a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow. If SharePoint 2013 platform is missing, you need to install and configure **Workflow Manager** for your farm.
[image]
More information about installing and configuring Workflow Manager, you can refer to:
[Workflow Manager Configuration For SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/workflow-manager-configuration-for-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: That's it exactly!  I was using the 2010 workflow and so that option was not available.  Thank you so much!